# Laravel Ajax route on other PC in the same network not work return 404

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I Have an Application under developement, i want to put it into production on a local network.

when i access other computers Ajax requests in GET Method return 4040.

This is a problem with the routes.

I do not know what to do.

on the local pc i have bar_app.test/*** all other route

on other computers i have 192.168.1.8/bar_app/public **** all other route

when Ajax get

```
const dtTax = dtTaxTableDataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: 'admin/get-taxes',
```

a got http://192.168.1.8/admin/get-taxes

not http://192.168.1.8/bar_app/public/admin/get-taxes

Laravel Route

```
  Route::get('/admin/get-taxes', [TaxController::class, 'allTaxes'])->name('tax.indexAjax');
```

Comment: try using nginx to run your laravel application. Maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/vicgonvt/cd0431a5cdc043ebab7f4954f7b4d471) will help. or run a apache server

Comment: i run a apache server, but not work

Comment: I do recommend to configure your apache and host settings. You can check this [blog](https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b)